# How to find out the most appear numbers from the String?

Tags: java, string, frequency

I have a `String` which contains numbers in a comma separated form. and I want to extract the most appears numbers from the String.
For example I have a String like..

```
String str="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,19,18,4";
```

from the above str i need 4 because 4 is two times in str.

same as

```
String str2="1,2,3,4,6,4,3,9";
```

from the above str2 i need 3,4

In case of all numbers are unique then i need first one.

suggest me better approach.

Comment: which will take a few time to find out the numbers, because str has a lot of numbers.

Comment: For a start, I wouldn't use a String as converting it to numbers could take longer than the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code

```
public class StringCheck {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,1,4,33,33,33";
        String result = "";
        String[] arr1 = input.split(",");

        System.out.println("Input is : " + input);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            int k = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                if (arr1[i].equals(arr1[j])) {
                    k++;
                    if (k == 2) {
                        if (result.contains(arr1[i])) {
                            break;
                        }
                        result = result + arr1[i] + ",";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Result is " + result);
    }
}
```

Below will be output

```
Input is : 1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,1,4,33,33,33
Result is 1,2,3,4,33,
```

Let me know if there are any queries...

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

I would have an array of map of integers to count each number, and variable to store the number with the highest count.

Split the string into a list of numbers, and loop over the list.

Each time you look at a new number, increment its counter in the map, and if that count is greater than the current highest count, change the current highest to the current. At the end of the string, return the current highest.

Note that, if you also store the number with the second biggest count, you can optimise slightly by exiting the loop early, when there are not enough numbers left to allow the second highest count to exceed the highest.

Answer (score 2):

You can tokenize the string using `java.util.StringTokenizer` using `,` as the separator, then strip off the leading and trailing spaces from each token using `String.trim()`, then store them into an array of `int`s using `Integer.parseInt()` function. Then you can count them easily.

For counting:

If you have a small range of numbers, then you can simply create a counter array and use each number as an index to that array. If not, then you can use `HashMap` or something like that.

Comment: Would personally recommend using `java.util.Scanner`, `"\\s*,\\s*"` as the delimiter and the method `nextInt` to retrieve the integers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a homework, I'll suggest a general idea without the code:

- Start by splitting the string on the `','` characters
- Create an initially empty map of `Integer` to `Integer` with the counts
- Go through the parts you've got back from the split, and parse them as `int` values
- For each value, see if there is a corresponding item in the map; if there is a number there, increment it; otherwise, add an entry with the new number and `1`.
- Once you're done with the tokens, go through the map and find the max value
- If the max is `1`, return the first token
- If the max is not `1`, go through the map again, and collect all keys where the value is equal to max

This approach lets you work with very large numbers, and it does not discriminate between numbers with and without leading zeros. In other words, it will identify `3` in `1,2,03,3,3,2` sequence as a unique winner, not as a tie with `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Transform your String into a list of numbers.

Remember what the first number of the list is.

Sort the list of numbers.

Iterate over the list and keep

- the number of occurrences of the current number.
- the current max number of occurrences of a number
- the number of distinct numbers you met
- the set of numbers that have a number of occurrences equals to the max

At each iteration, if the current number is equal to the current max, add the current number to the result. If it's greater than the current max, clear the set of results and add the current number to the results.

At the end of the loop, if the size of the result set is equal to the number of distinct numbers, return the first number you remembered before sorting the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) and [Guava collect](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html).

Outline:

1. Split String into list of words
2. Count the frequency of each word and create a map `Word -> Count`
3. Invert to create a Multimap `Count -> Words`
4. Convert to a sorted NavigableMap
5. Get Words with highest count
6. Return Words with hightest count

Code:

```
public class HighestCountFinder {


    public static ImmutableSet<String> findWordsWithGreatestCount(String wordsString) {
        List<String> words = split(wordsString, ",");

        Map<String, Integer> wordsToCounts = toMapWithCounts(words);

        Multimap<Integer, String> countsToWords = toInverseMultimap(wordsToCounts);

        NavigableMap<Integer, Collection<String>> countsToWordsSorted = toNavigableMap(countsToWords);

        Collection<String> wordsWithHighestCount = lastValue(countsToWordsSorted);

        return ImmutableSet.copyOf(wordsWithHighestCount);
    }


    public static ImmutableList<String> split(String wordsString, String separator) {
        Iterable<String> parts = Splitter.on(separator).split(wordsString);
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(parts);
    }


    public static ImmutableMap<String, Integer> toMapWithCounts(Iterable<String> entries) {
        Multiset<String> entriesWithCounts = HashMultiset.create(entries);
        return toMap(entriesWithCounts);
    }


    public static <E> ImmutableMap<E, Integer> toMap(Multiset<E> multiset) {
        ImmutableMap.Builder<E, Integer> immutableMapBuilder = ImmutableMap.builder();
        for (Multiset.Entry<E> entry : multiset.entrySet()) {
            immutableMapBuilder.put(entry.getElement(), entry.getCount());
        }
        return immutableMapBuilder.build();
    }


    public static <K, V> ImmutableMultimap<V, K> toInverseMultimap(Map<K, V> map) {
        Multimap<K, V> multimap = Multimaps.forMap(map);
        return ImmutableMultimap.copyOf(multimap).inverse();
    }


    public static <K, V> NavigableMap<K, Collection<V>> toNavigableMap(Multimap<K, V> multimap) {
        return new TreeMap<>(multimap.asMap());
    }


    public static <V> V lastValue(NavigableMap<?, V> navigableMap) {
        return navigableMap.lastEntry().getValue();
    }
}
```